# Получение данных из .grd

Tags: c++, input, io

Есть .grd файл размером 13 ГБ. Он содержит данные высот SRTM15 Plus. Как получить из него значения определенной точки по широте/долготе?

Сам файл бинарный, начинается с `CDF.................lon...QЃ....lat...ЁБ............Conventions.........COARDS/CF-1.0.......title...........Produced by grdmath.....history........‹grdmath -V -fg /geosat2/srtm15_data/land//land.grd /geosat2/srtm15_data/topo//debug/polished.grd AND = /geosat2/srtm15_data/topo//world.grd.....description........+Derived from the full resolution shorelinen.....GMT_version.........4.5.12 [64-bit].............lon.....................long_nam`

Comment: Толку от приведения бинарного файла в таком виде ноль. Описание формата вообще имеется?

Comment: нет, в сети толком ничего не нашел, а сам файл отсюда ftp://topex.ucsd.edu/pub/srtm15_plus/

Comment: Во-первых, стоит начать изучение с утилиты, которая это сгенерировала: http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/projects/gmt
Оно opensource, можно многое нарыть.

А во-вторых, можно поспрашивать на gis-lab.info, возможно, нужный велосипед уже изобретён.

И да, если задача не "извлечь значения чёрт знает откуда", а "получить высоту в определённой точке", проще скачать файлы hgt. Там формат совсем простой.